# How to check if a certain element is at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've seen plenty of solutions that are based on the page scroll. Is there a way - based on page size alone that a certain element (a div for instance) in javascript (if possible angular) know that this element itself is near the bottom of the page?

I have a this directive which creates an element:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('sampleElement',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/sample.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
                // code to detect if it's near or at the bottom of the page and do something
            }
        }
    }
);
```

On my html

```
<div class="col-md-5">Sample element</div>
```

I want my directive to detect that it is almost or at the bottom of the page so that it can do something based on the size of the page alone at which scrolling doesn't matter. It's kinda like something that's not event driven but it's just a check that the directive can know how long is the page, and know if it positioned at bottom or not. That's all.